# Sql Db Backups on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL database setup on Azure. I was trying to understand if it was automatically backed up or if it is something that I need to setup. Could I get some feedback on this please?

Comment: Are you using `Azure SQL Databases` (PaaS offering) or have you installed `SQL Server in a VM`?

Comment: I am using Azure SQL Databases (PaaS offering)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure SQL Databases are automatically backed up for you. You don't need to explicitly set anything up. As far as frequency with which the backup happens, from this [`link`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-automated-backups/):

> For local database backups, full database backups happen weekly,
>   differential database backups happen hourly, and transaction log
>   backups happen every five minutes. The first full backup is scheduled
>   immediately after a database is created. It usually completes within
>   30 minutes, but it can take longer when the database is of a
>   significant size.

Furthermore, the duration for which the backups are kept (so that go can go back in time and restore them) depends on the service  tier of your database. From the same [`link`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-automated-backups/):

> Each SQL Database backup has a retention period that is based on the
>   service-tier of the database. The retention period for a database in
>   the:
>
> - Basic service tier is seven days.
> - Standard service tier is 35 days.
> - Premium service tier is 35 days.